# Linear transformation graph Problem

Tags: linear-transformations

The below is taken from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices).

Question: What does the "P" in the graph below represent? And how this graph is proved?

I got confused when I saw the definition on Wikipedia...

[image: Wikipedia linear transformation graph]

Comment: $P$ is the transition matrix from $B'$ to $B$

Comment: $P$ is the matrix encoding the change of basis from $B'$ to $B$. The fact that the diagram commutes---that $P^{-1} A P = A'$---is just a matter of unwinding the definitions.

Comment: In order to understand what the diagram conveys, I suggest you look at [these online notes](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs485/2006sp/LinAlg_Complete.pdf), starting with the "change of basis" section on page 235. While wikipedia is a handy resource for those who are already familiar with the subject, it is no substitute for a textbook.

Comment: ok, I will take a look, thank you for your material.